# pjsip pj_timer_heap_schedule crashes

Tags: c, pjsip

I'm trying to make a simple timer that fires a specific call back when its time come.
I have written this code:

```
void testTimer()
{
    pj_timer_heap_t *timer_heap;
    pj_timer_entry   registrationTimer;
    char *username="test_data";
    pj_timer_entry_init(&registrationTimer, 50, username, &on_timer_event);
    pj_time_val delay;
    delay.sec = 5;
    delay.msec = 0;
    pj_status_t status = pj_timer_heap_create(global.pool, 256, &timer_heap);
    status=pj_timer_heap_schedule(timer_heap,&registrationTimer, &delay);
}
```

I don't know whats wrong with the code. This code crashes on `pj_timer_heap_schedule`.I am unable to figure out whats missing. Pls Help.

Comment: What do you mean by *crash*?

Comment: I am exporting a class which contains some methods as a DLL file and I'm using it from a C# application, and when I call testTimer(), my c sharp application crashes.

Comment: Any chance the call to `pj_timer_heap_create` failed and you are passing a bad `timer_heap` to `pj_timer_heap_schedule`? Other than that, you may want to try pjsua_schedule_timer (see http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__BASE.htm#ga4b3f7529ece820df563c4b1a4f4a649b). Simpler to use. Finally, I think your code has another bug: `registrationTimer` will go out of scope and far as I can remember, it has to remain valid until the callback fires.

Comment: Thanks chr for your reply, pj_timer_heap_create returns PJ_SUCCESS so I'm sure that there is no problem with the creation of the timer heap.

I put registrationTimer within this method scope to simplify the code, but the it's defined outside that scope in the real code.

I tried to use 
    pjsua_schedule_timer(&registrationTimer,&delay); 
but it crashes too in this method. Would you please write a simple example on how to use pjsua_schedule_timer. I will be so thankful.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little impossible to know the problem without the

> pj_timer_heap_schedule

function

Comment: It's part of `pjsip`, as mentioned in the title. PJSIP is open source. See http://www.pjsip.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Try and initialize as

```
`pj_bzero(&registrationTimer, sizeof(registrationTimer));`
```

then ensure you have done

```
`registrationTimer.id = PJSUA_INVALID_ID;`
`registrationTimer.cb = &my_callback;`
```

finally don't forget to define and declare your callback *my_callback*

Good luck